# PHP PDF writing with multiple queries and data arrays

Tags: php, fpdf

Hey guys I'm just trying to get this stupid thing working and I can tweak it from there,
I start with an array, which will be transferred in most likely via $_POST,

```
$cleanArray = array( array('type'=>'berries', 'numb'=>'5555'), 
                     array('type'=>'melons', 'numb'=>'686') );
```

I then declare some data arrays that will provide the structure (if there's a better way to do this particular step, LET ME KNOW!), this is three of the types, there's six total. The query is the **unique** query that each type needs to return the correct information, while the sizes are the **field sizes** that are for that item in the pdf.

```
$dataShape = array(
    'berries'   => array(   'sizes' => array( 0 => 25, 1 => 20, 3 => 10, 4 => 15, 5 => 10, 6 => 20, 7 => 20, 8 => 10, 9 => 15, 10 => 10, 11 => 15, 12 => 10, 13 => 10, 14 => 10, 15 => 10, 16 => 10, 17 => 10, 18 => 10, 19 => 200 ),
                            'query' => array( 'shipper, po, commodity as comm, count, size, label, variety, pack_date AS date, grower_lot AS lot, CONCAT(color1, "-", color2) AS color, CONCAT(sizing1, "-", sizing2, " / ", "sizing3", "-", sizing4 ) AS size, CONCAT(firmness1, "-", firmness2) AS firmness, CONCAT(scars_count1, "-", scars_count2) AS scars_count, CONCAT(bruise_count2, "-", bruise_count2) AS bruise_count, CONCAT(decay_count1, "-", decay_count2) AS green, CONCAT(sugar_brix1, "-", sugar_brix2) brix, rating, comments')),
    'citrus'    => array(   'sizes' => array( 0 => 25, 1 => 20, 3 => 10, 4 => 15, 5 => 10, 6 => 20, 7 => 20, 8 => 10, 9 => 15, 10 => 10, 11 => 15, 12 => 10, 13 => 10, 14 => 10, 15 => 10, 16 => 10, 17 => 10, 18 => 10, 19 => 200 ),
                            'query' => array('shipper, po, commodity as comm, count, size, label, variety, pack_date AS date, grower_lot AS lot, CONCAT(color1, "-", color2) AS color, CONCAT(texture1, "-", texture2) AS texture, CONCAT(puff1, "-", puff2) AS puff, CONCAT(scar1, "-", scar2) AS scars, CONCAT(solidity1, "-", solidity2) AS solidity, CONCAT(green1, "-", green2) AS green, CONCAT(sugar_brix1, "-", sugar_brix2) brix, rating, comments')),
    'melons'    => array(   'sizes' => array( 0 => 25, 1 => 20, 3 => 10, 4 => 15, 5 => 10, 6 => 20, 7 => 20, 8 => 10, 9 => 15, 10 => 10, 11 => 15, 12 => 10, 13 => 10, 14 => 10, 15 => 10, 16 => 10, 17 => 10, 18 => 200 ),
                            'query' => array('shipper, po, commodity as comm, count, size, label, variety, pack_date AS date, grower_lot AS lot, CONCAT(color1, "-", color2) AS color, CONCAT(ground_color1, "-", ground_color2) AS ground_color, CONCAT(texture1, "-", texture2) AS texture, CONCAT(scar1, "-", scar2) AS scars, CONCAT(solidity1, "-", solidity2) AS solidity, CONCAT(cut1, "-", cut2) AS cut, CONCAT(sugar_brix1, "-", sugar_brix2) brix, rating, comments')),
);
```

I then try to query based on the type, and structure of the type, it will name each array the `type` name, and turn each section into a subarray. [You can see it here.](http://pastebin.com/r3h5gQCL)

```
foreach($cleanArray as $key=>$val) { echo $key;
    $result[$cleanArray[$key]['type']]
    = $dbc->fetch_array("SELECT ".implode(',',$dataShape[ $cleanArray[$key]['type'] ]['query'])." FROM `"
                        .$cleanArray[$key]['type']."` WHERE (status = '0' OR status = '1') AND `report_key` = "
                        .$cleanArray[$key]['numb']);
}
```

I then try to add pages, and iterate stuff, this does not work. It should use the keys a single time to get column names, then iterate out the keys values until there spent. If the values are less then twelve rows long (24 rows total, as comments takes up its own row) iterate blank rows until 12 rows are there.

```
foreach($result as $fruitType=>$fruitTypeArray) {
  $nameKeys = array_keys($fruitTypeArray[0]);
  $i=0; $pdf->AddPage('L');  

  foreach($dataShape[$fruitType]['sizes'] as $dataShapevalue) { 
    $pdf->Cell($dataShapevalue6,ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$nameKeys[$i++])),1,0,'L',1); 
  }

  // go to next row
  $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

  foreach($dataShape[$fruitType]['sizes'] as $dataShapeValue) { 
  foreach($fruitTypeArray as $queryName=>$queryValue) { 
  if(!$queryName=='comments') {
    $pdf->Cell($dataShapeValue,6,$queryValue,1,0,'L',1);
  } else {

  // go to next row
  $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

    $pdf->Cell($dataShapeValue,6,ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$nameKeys[$i++])),1,0,'L',1); 

  // go to next row
  $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to scrap and rewrite everything, here's code for those who care.

```
<?php

    // temp array
    $cleanArray = array( array('type'=>'berries', 'numb'=>'55555'), 
                         array('type'=>'melons', 'numb'=>'686') );

require('class/pdfwriter/report.php');
require('class/dbconnect.class.php');
require('class/perms.class.php');

include('class/structure.php');

$dbc = Database::obtain(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,0);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak('margin','1');

    $pad = 277;

    $dbc->connect();

    foreach($cleanArray as $key) {
        $data[] = getSlice($key['type']); // returns types query and cellpad settings
    }

    $i=0;
    foreach($data as $key) {
        $product[$cleanArray[$i]['type']] = $dbc->fetch_array(" SELECT ".implode(',',$key['query'])." FROM `{$cleanArray[$i]['type']}` WHERE (status = '0' OR status = '1') AND `report_key` = {$cleanArray[$i++]['numb']}");
    }

    $current=$i=0;
    foreach($product as $key) {

        $empty = 15 - count($key);
        $margin = $pad / count($key[0])+1;
        $comment = $margin * (count($key[0])-1);
        $total = $margin * (count($key[0])-5);

        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',15);
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$cleanArray[$i]['type'])),0,0,'C');
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
        $pdf->Ln(5);

    // column names
    foreach($key[0] as $name=>$value) {
            if($name!='comments') { 
                $pdf->Cell($margin,5,strtoupper(str_replace('_',' ',$name)),1,0,'C',1);
            } else { $pdf->Cell($comment,5,'',0,1,'L'); }
    }


    // row values
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',7);
    foreach($key as $array) {
        foreach($array as $name=>$value) {
            if($name!='comments') { 
                $pdf->Cell($margin,5,$value,1,0,'C',0);
            } else { 
                $pdf->Cell(0,5,'',0,1,'L');
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
                $pdf->Cell($comment,5,'COMMENTS:',1,1,'L',0); 
                $pdf->SetFont('Times','',7);
            }
        }

    }

    while($empty) {
        $innerCount = count($key[0])-1;
        while($innerCount) { 
            $pdf->Cell($margin,5,'',1,0,'C',0);
            $innerCount--;
        }
            $pdf->Cell(0,5,'',0,1,'L');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
            $pdf->Cell($comment,5,'COMMENTS:',1,1,'L',0); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Times','',7);
        $empty--;
    }

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
        $pdf->Cell($margin,5,'',0,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell($margin,5,'',0,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell($margin,6,'TOTAL',0,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell($margin,5,'',1,0,'L',0);

        $pdf->Cell($total,5,'',1,1,'4',0);

        $pdf->Ln(3);

        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',9);
        $pdf->Cell($pad,5,'This report (including any attachments) contains confidential information for a specific individual and purpose. If you are not the intended recipient',0,1,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell($pad,5,'you should delete this message and are hearby notified that any disclosure, copying, or distribution of this report is strictly prohibited',0,1,'C',0);

    if(++$current!=count($product)){$pdf->AddPage('L');}
    $i++;
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```